# Function that takes 1 argument spits back undefined method `grabTweets' for PagesHelper:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to write a very simple function that feeds whatever text someone enters into an input field, into a function which searches Twitter and returns some value.

In my `home.html.erb` file I have this code, but I'm not sure if calling the @tweetArray instance variable which should call my grabTweets function is the right way to go about things.

```
    <%= form_for(@tweetArray) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :grabTweets %>
    <% end %>
```

In my `pages helper` file I have:

```
  @tweetArray = grabTweets(:grabTweets)

  def grabTweets(mySearch)
    @tweet = Twitter.search( "mySearch +" "[pic] "+" path.com/p/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
    @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
    urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
    end
  end
```

My page just shows this error `undefined method grabTweets for PagesHelper:Module`. What do I put in my `home.html.erb` file to call this code correctly?

Edit:

Updated my code in `home.html.erb`

```
    <%= form_for(grabTweets) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :search %>
    <% end %>
```

Does that make more sense?

And then in my `pages controller`

```
@tweetArray = grabTweets(":search")


def grabTweets(mySearch)
    @tweet = Twitter.search( mySearch + "[pic] "+" path.com/p/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
    @tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
    urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings
    end
  end
```

I'm still getting an error `undefined local variable or method grabTweets` in `home.html.erb`

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding what you're aiming for here. form_for accepts some sort of record. You'd pass it a :tweet or @tweet. So typically you'd set it up inside your controller before rendering your view, and then for f.text_field you'd give it an attribute of that record.

Comment: I'm trying to get the form_for to execute a twitter search with the code in my controller (I took it out of the helper, put it back in the controller). What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: @ShaneO'Connor So would I search grabTweets with the attribute being the 1 argument? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With a Model

Assuming you have an @tweet object:

```
<%= form_for(@tweet) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
<% end %>
```

Then, depending on how you have your routes set up, when a user submits the form it will hit your `find_tweets` action. You could have a route set up for `/tweets` that hits the `find_tweets` action (call it what you like).

In your controller you'd have:

```
def find_tweets
  @tweets = Twitter.search( params[:tweet][:search] + "[pic] "+" path.com/p/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
    tweet = "#{status.text}" #class = string
    urls = URI::extract(@tweet, "http") #returns an array of strings

    { 
      :tweet => tweet,
      :urls => urls
    }
  end

  @tweets
end
```

That should get you an `@tweets` that would an array of hashes with a tweet and urls. I haven't tested any of this but I hope it'll point you in the right direction.

## Without a Model

To do this without a model you can use `form_tag`.

```
<%= form_tag '/tweets/find_tweets' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "search" %>
<% end %>
```

Your controller wouldn't change much, but you'd likely access your search params using `params[:search]` instead.

Comment: Thanks Shane. It does point me in the right direction. My main confusion was how to set up the search field code to interact correctly with the method in the controller. I know you haven't tested the code but I had one question: how is :search funneled into the `find_tweets` method you've written? Does that funnel into the mySearch variable that appears after Twitter.search?

Comment: My bad. I updated my post. I replaced mySearch with params[:tweet][:search]. It'll probably be something like params[:tweet][:search], but either way you'll need to pull it from the params.

Comment: Thank you. Going to play with this now

Comment: One additional question: you mention setting up routes. Currently the only thing I've done in the routes file is redirect "/" to `pages#home`. What would I need to do in the routes.rb file?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Routes can have quite a bit to them. I'm not terribly good with routes, but off the top of my head you could do something like: map.tweets '/tweets/find_tweets', :controller => 'tweets', :action => 'find_tweets'. That's probably not the best solution, but it would direct all traffic to /tweets/find_tweets to your find_tweets action.

Comment: One last thing, I have no Tweets model. I have no models at all, actually. That seems to be a problem as I'm now getting `undefined model name` as my error